# How to print two table by selecting one of the choices from selectInput() in Shiny App?

Tags: r, csv, drop-down-menu, dataframe, shiny

I have 4 dataframes and I want to print two dataframe a1 and a2 on selecting "Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 31" from `selectInput` choices but it get splitted into two options in `selectInput` like Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 311" and Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 312" and same case with dataframe b1 and b2.

And in second table i.e., a2 and b2 I want to upload text, I'm able to upload it but I'm not getting table a1 and a2 on selecting "Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 31".

```
a1 <- read.csv(file.path("E:/Puma/Manuals/Smoke tables csv/AT1240E_Smoke_Meter-4.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)
a2 <- read.csv(file.path("E:/Manual/error7.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)

#b1<- read.csv(file.path("E:/Puma/Manuals/Smoke tables csv/AT1240E_Smoke_Meter-21.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)
#b2 <- read.csv(file.path("E:/Manual/error15.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)


library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("readable"),
                     titlePanel(h3("PUMA", style = "color:black")),
                     sidebarLayout(
                     wellPanel(
                     tags$head(
                     tags$style("body {background-color: pink; }")),

  selectInput("error", strong("ERROR MESSAGE:", style = "color:brown" ),
             choices =c("Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 31"= c("a1", "a2"),
                        "Door is open (Timeout key)-Error number 15 / 100"= c("b1","b2")
                                     ),
                                     selected = NULL
                         ),
  textInput("Possible.cause", label="Add a new Possible.cause ", value=NULL),
  textInput("Check", label="Add a new Check", value=NULL),
  textInput("Remedy", label="Add a new Remedy", value=NULL),
  actionButton("addButton", "UPLOAD!")


                       ),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(h2("TABLE", style = "color:brown"), verbatimTextOutput("error")),

    tags$head(tags$style("#error{color:navy;
               font-size: 17px;
               font-style: bold;
               font-family: 'Roboto';
               background-color: #FFFFFF;
               border-radius: 16px !important;
               max-height: none;
               position: absolute;
               text-align: left;
               spacing=l;
               border-width: bold;
               border-style: solid;
               border-color: #f44336 !important;
             }"))

                ),
                 width = 12)
                )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

output$error <- renderPrint ({

get(input$error)

 })
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- a2
  row.names(a2) <- NULL

  observe({

if(input$addButton > 0) {

  newLine <- isolate(c(input$Possible.cause, input$Check, input$Remedy))
  isolate(values$df <- rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
  write.csv(values$df,file.path("E:/Manual/error7.csv"), sep = "," ,
            row.names = FALSE,append=FALSE)

  }
  })          

  })

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On doing little changes in my code I got my answer as I want. Yiipee :)

```
 a1 <- read.csv(file.path("E:/Puma/Manuals/Smoke tables csv/AT1240E_Smoke_Meter-4.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)
 a2 <- read.csv(file.path("E:/Manual/error7.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)
 new <- list(a1, a2)

 b1 <- read.csv(file.path("E:/Puma/Manuals/Smoke tables csv/AT1240E_Smoke_Meter-21.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)
 b2 <- read.csv(file.path("E:/Manual/error15.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)
 new1 <- list(b1,b2)

 selectInput("error", strong("ERROR MESSAGE:", style = "color:brown" ),
                                     choices =c("Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 31"= "new",
                                                "Door is open (Timeout key)-Error number 15 / 100"= "new1")

                                     ),
                                     selected = NULL

                         )
```